# Delphi XE2 compile error: package compiling tries to create directory?

Tags: delphi, compilation, directory, package, targets

Why am I getting this error, compiling a package in Delphi XE2 32bits platform:

> c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad
>   studio\9.0\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets(465,5): error MSB3191: Unable
>   to create directory "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop
>   CS2\Plug-Ins\Import-Export". Access to the path 'C:\Program
>   Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS2\Plug-Ins\Import-Export' is denied.

I found that directory in the package resource directory and conditional search path, and I have removed it from there, but I am still getting this error. Where does it find this path and why does it attempt to create the folder?

This error started to appear when I change the unit output directory to a relative path, that is: "..\source\win32"

Comment: Don't you have that folder configured as a unit output directory, or a package output directory in its project options ?

Comment: @TLama no it does not appear under the unit output or the package output.

Comment: This is puzzling to me, irst time it ever happened. Is there any way I can search for the path inside the project options? Or maybe is it possible that the package is still pointing to some previous compilation files (Though I have deleted all bpl and dcp and dcu files

Comment: I wonder why this has been voted down. It was a legitimate question.

Comment: There are just "random" downvoters...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by creating new package and copying the source file of old package. I think some old info was left incorrectly inside the old package.